# Dropdown selection loads image and another dropdown menu loads info on another column

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have to make a dropdown menu in which selection of an option loads an image under it, and it also shows another dropdown menu under the image with options related to the selection. 
Now this second dropdown menu, when I select an option, I need an image and some info to load in another column on the same page. I'm new to JS so a bit too ignorant.

```html
<div class="row">
 <select>
  <option value="1">Please select an author:</option>
  <option value="2">Gillian Flynn</option>
  <option value="3">Robert Galbraith</option>
  <option value="4">Khaled Hosseini</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange = function() {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleContent");
  
  for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = 'none';
  }  
  
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  
  document.getElementById(value).style.display = "block";
  
}
```

```css
.toggleContent{
  display:none;
}

.defaultContent{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <select>
  <option value="1">Please select an author:</option>
  <option value="2">Gillian Flynn</option>
  <option value="3">Robert Galbraith</option>
  <option value="4">Khaled Hosseini</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div id="1" class="toggleContent defaultContent">11111111111111111111</div>
<div id="2" class="toggleContent">22222222222222222222</div>
<div id="3" class="toggleContent">33333333333333333333</div>
<div id="4" class="toggleContent">44444444444444444444</div>
```